# Image inside of ImaveView larger than frame, position the top of image to top of ImageView

Tags: java, android, listview, imageview

I have a `listView` row that I am completely filling with an `imageView`, which is `190dp` high. The image that gets loaded is quite large, because I am pulling it from the web. The image is 640x812.

When the image gets loaded in the `imageView` it seems to be centered. However, I would like the top of the image to line up with the top of the `imageView` so that the users can see the top of the image, which has writing on it.

Here is what I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="110dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/viewpoint_imageView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@drawable/default_background"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/viewpoint_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="16dp"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="0dp"
        android:lines="3"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:shadowRadius="2"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

From what I read, using `fitStart` was what I needed, but that didn't help at all.

[image]

Comment: and how do you load the images?

Comment: @pelotasplus - I lazy load them from a url using `Universal Image Loader`: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Answer (score 0):

As i see you are using the Universal Image Loader, you need to add this line:

```
options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()                     
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY).build();
```

And use this attributes in your ImageView:

```
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="matrix"
```

ImageScaleType.EXACTLY makes the images scale the right way.

If you want to align the image at any side of the ImageView you should use those lines:

```
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

Note that the ImageView parent must be RelativeLayout so the alignParentTop attribute to work.

Comment: Which one are you trying the fitXY , or alignParentTop ?

Comment: You are including everything, without the alignParentTop attribute right?

Comment: Correct. That is what I have used.

Comment: You can try making the width and height of the image view to be match_parent.

Answer (score 0):

Use scale type of Image view as `FIT_CENTER`.